# What is the difference between the whatis and apropos commands?

Tags: command-line, centos, rhel

CentOS 6.3 / RHEL 6.3

Can someone please explain the difference between the `whatis` command and the `apropos` command? I noticed that both appear to be installed by default and I'm not sure what the difference is between them.

Comment: Probably `yum provides whatis` and `yum provides apropos` will both list the same _man_, _man-db_ or similar package. Actually `whatis` is the same as `man -f` and `apropos` the same as `man -k`. See whether those two switch's description in `man man` is easier to understand.

Answer (score 12):

`whatis` displays one-line manual page descriptions, intended to give you a general idea of what a program do,

while `apropos` searches the manual page names and descriptions, intended to help you to learn what program to use when performing a certain job.

#### Some examples

Say, I want to know what does `df` program do. `whatis` gives me answer.

```
$ whatis df
df (1)               - report file system disk space usage
```

And now, I want to unzip an archive. `apropos` gives me some choises for consideration.

```
$ apropos unzip
bunzip2 (1)          - a block-sorting file compressor, v1.0.6
funzip (1)           - filter for extracting from a ZIP archive in a pipe
gunzip (1)           - compress or expand files
lz (1)               - gunzips and shows a listing of a gzip'd tar'd archive
preunzip (1)         - prefix delta compressor for Aspell
unzip (1)            - list, test and extract compressed files in a ZIP archive
unzipsfx (1)         - self-extracting stub for prepending to ZIP archives
uz (1)               - gunzips and extracts a gzip'd tar'd archive
```

**UPDATE**:

Since both `whatis` and `apropos` search man database, you can only get info on what's already installed on your system.

Answer (score 3):

`whatis ls` lists the manual pages for `ls`, `apropos ls` lists all manual pages that contain `ls` in their title. The first list here gives 2 entries, the second 1385.

Answer (score 1):

Based on their `info` pages, both commands "search a set of database files containing short descriptions of system commands for keywords". For `whatis`, "only complete word matches are displayed."

Answer (score 0):

They act the same with one difference:

- `whatis` needs a **accurate** parameter:

  ```
  whatis passwd
  ```
- `apropos` needs **a string or first characters** of something that you know:

  ```
  apropos pass
  ```

Comment: Should that say " a string ***of*** first characters" rather than ***or***? If you do indeed mean "or" (and not "of"), then that would suggest that `apropos sswd` would also work - which (after a quick check) does actually work... you might want to add that to your answer (for the sake of clarity). :-)

Answer (score 0):

A difference I haven't seen in the answers above: `apropos` searches "manual pages and descriptions", while `whatis` searches the manual page names only. The matching behaviour (regular expressions vs exact matching) can be overridden by supplying `-r` for regExp (implicit in `apropos` but the option can still be set in both), -w for wildcard (can be set in both) and -e for exact matching (implicit and unavailable in `whatis`, can be set in `apropos`).

(Also `man -f` is equivalent to `whatis` and `man -k` is equivalent to `apropos`.)